# Why I sometime get 'The connection was lost' error?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

so, I am making an app and want to GET data from my own server using alamofire. but I don't know why, I SOMETIME get the error

> HTTP load failed (error code: -1005 [1:57]) .
>   finished with error -
>   code: -1005.  error: The network connection was lost.

and this only happen when I try to get data to my own server. I try to compare to get data from other server, from darksky API, and I never get the error. here is the code I use to get data from my own server and to darksky API.

the error usually occurred when .....

after I start the app, and I push the home button ( so the app enter the background state), and when I back to the app, and at this time, I usually get the error.

so maybe I got the error when `prepareDataBeforeEnterForeground` is triggered. not always happened, and I don't know why it happened only to my server, and I need to know how to fix this.

does the error comes from my code or from the server?

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

    class ViewController: UIViewController {


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            getData()

            getPrepareDataBeforeEnterForeground() // using notification center

        }

        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)

            getData()
        }


        func getData() {

        // to make request to my own server OR to DarkSky API


            let url = URL(string: "https://")
            let parameters : [String:String] = ["xxx": "xxxx"]


            Alamofire.request(url!, method: .get, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { (response) in

                switch response.result {
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                case .success(let value) :
                    // parse the data
                }
            }
        }



        func getPrepareDataBeforeEnterForeground() {

            // to trigger some function after the enter the background state
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.prepareDataBeforeEnterForeground), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
        }

        @objc func prepareDataBeforeEnterForeground() {
           getData()
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For reference, your error code correlates to:

```
kCFURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost  = -1005
```

From my own personal experience, I get this error when the parameters I'm trying to send to the server are incorrect or malformed.

In your case, I can't seem to see where you are accepting `parameters` or defining it, so that might be your issue.

If its coming from your server, you will have to check the error logs for the server software (Apache, nginx, etc) (if you have them).

---

Here is an example of a valid request:

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
    "foo": "bar",
    "baz": ["a", 1],
    "qux": [
        "x": 1,
        "y": 2,
        "z": 3
    ]
]
Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/post", method: .post, parameters: parameters)
```

To add on, it doesn't appear that you are sending any headers either, so you could be causing your server to reject the request completely.

Comment: did you have the same issue? I mean, not always got an error when sending the request, just sometimes? could you please little bit elaborate more about incorrect or malformed parameters? because I often get my data from server, so I assume I write the correct parameter

Comment: @sarah I have had the issue. You see where you have `parameters: parameters` ?

Comment: Nowhere do you actually define the variable `parameters`

Comment: my bad, In actual yes I have that parameter declaration, I forgot to copy that to stackoverflow. but in my parameter, I don't declare it as ( : Parameters) , i just leave it alone or declare it as [String:Any]. will try it

Comment: @sarah okay. That might be the issue, as I know `Alamofire` needs to encode the parameters properly according to the type of request you're sending (POST, in your case).